# Promise.all() not successful when pushing async promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have these two snippets of code:

**A** (https://repl.it/repls/HarmlessSupportiveUpgrades)

```
array = []
const promise = async (i) => console.log(i)
for (const num of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
    array.push(promise(num))
}

Promise.all(array)
```

**B**(https://repl.it/repls/ColdHealthyAssignment)

```
array = []
for (const num of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
    array.push(async (i) => console.log(i))
}

Promise.all(array)
```

I'm confused as to why the A will successfully print to the console, but B won't. How come?

Comment: Because in the second case you never *call* the `async` function.

Comment: You're never invoking the method in example B. If you pushed `(async (i) => console.log(i))(num)` to your array instead you'd see it work the same way

Comment: **B** probably needs to look more like this: `for (const num of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) array.push((async () => console.log(num))())` In your version, you are creating an array of `async` functions, not an array of promises. `Promise.all` expects an array of promises. So you need to actually invoke the async function each time around the loop (to get the Promise). Note that, in these examples, I don't think anything asynchronous is actually occurring because you are essentially creating a bunch of immediately-resolved promises.

Comment: If you do `console.log(array)` (or use a debugger), you'll see that the array contains functions instead of promises in the second snippet

Comment: In B, you are pushing the function declarations into an array instead of function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first snippet you are calling the function with num as parameter.

But on the second you are pushing function declarations to the array

if you replace

```
array.push(async (i) => console.log(i))
```

on the second snippet with

```
array.push((async (i) => console.log(i))(num))
```

it will work the same way as the first snippet.